# How to create ResponseBody instance for mocking retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

How to create `ResponseBody` object for mocking the below service?

```
public interface SBRestfulApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("authentication/google_login/")
    Call<ResponseBody> auth(@Field("id_token") String idToken);
}
```

Written the below class for mocking, but unable to create the `MediaType` as it constructor is private.

Any alternative for handling it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ResponseBody` has a few static `create` methods you can use. And `MediaType` has a static `parse` method as well.